# change the share icons from the facebook, linkedin, google+, tweeter

Tags: facebook, icons, share, google-plus

I try to put in a page the share buttons of facebook, linkedin, google+, twitter

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button

but with another graphism.

Is there a 'simple' way to do so?
I can not really use css or jQuery are they are in an iframe

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom button with whatever CSS you wish to and then position the standard like button over it with 100% transparency.

Though you won't be able write custom event handlers (if that's what you wanted jquery for ) for those buttons. That's why in first place these buttons don't allow you to modify them.